# Is it possible in Google Analytics to have events/visit goal?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

My situation in Google Analytics is as follows:

Everytime, user clicks a particular element on my website, it is recorded as an event (call it EVENT1).
The problem is that my GA goal is to have at least three of those elements clicked per visit.
We can say that the goal is fulfilled when a user causes 3 EVENT1 events per one visit.

Is it possible to define this? 
I know it is possible to track number of pages/visit. But it is not what I am looking for, as there are many pages that does not include the element which can be clicked. 
I guess another way would be to use javascript and send "CLICKED 3 TIMES" event to GA. But I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Depends on you purpose - if all you need is to identify the users with three events you can build a custom segment (or multiple segments depending on the order of the events - look into sequences). However you cannot assign a value or have funnels view with segments.

Comment: All I need is to know the rate. How many people clicked on at least three "elements" during their visit in comparison to all the visits on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an advanced segment of the "sequence" type. Make every step the same event. Apply the segment to see the number of visitors included in that segment.

[image]